# How to build a polybar on rockky 9.3

Tags: i3

```
$ tar zxvf polybar-3.7.1.tar.gz
$ cd polybar-3.7.1
$ ./build.sh
```

```
--   Package 'libuv', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:556 (message):
A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:778 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
cmake/common/utils.cmake:45 (pkg_check_modules)
cmake/modules/FindLibUV.cmake:9 (find_package_impl)
cmake/libpoly.cmake:51 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:57 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/build/polybar-3.7.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Failed to generate build... read output to get a hint of what went wrong
```

```
$ rpm -qa | grep libuv
libuv-1.42.0-1.el9.x86_64
```

libuv is already installed

I think the location I'm looking for on build.sh is /usr/include/libuv

How can we solve this problem?

Is it possible to install i3-wm or polybar on rockky 9 by any chance?